# DRF: How to define a custom error message for UnsupportedMediaType exception during parsing

Tags: django, error-handling, django-rest-framework

**Question**

What's the easiest way to define and return a custom text error message when an 'Unsupported media type' error is raised by a Django Rest Framework parser?

**Some context**

I have the following APIView to handle a POST call:

```
class UploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, ]

    def post(self, request):
        # Question: Can this blob be simplied?
        if not request.content_type.startswith("multipart/form-data;"):
            msg = f"Expected content-type: multipart/form-data. But got: {request.content_type}"
            return Response(data=msg, status=status.HTTP_415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)

        serializer = ...
        ...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

As you can see, I check for the content type, and, if not as expect, I respond with a 415 message stating the desired content type. But this approach doesn't feel quite right. I think the handling and custom message belongs in the parser logic. Is there a better way to do this?

(I know I can define custom serialization validation error messages in serializer classes using the `error_messages` property of a field ([docs here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#error_messages)). However, I couldn't find anything similar for the parser; apart likely from creating a custom parser. Is that indeed the appropriate way to go?)